# Pause while converting from url to uiimage

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, nsdata, nsurl

I got an app, where i download images. I do it in this way:

```
NSString *imgURL = [@"http://www.kwikspik.com/static/" stringByAppendingString:spikFromTopic.user_image];
        NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:imgURL]];
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
        UIImageView *userImage =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,size,userImageSize,userImageSize)];
        userImage.image = image;
```

This code implement for really long time.

Is problem in internet connection? or maybe in my code?

Comment: do you try to load the image synchronously or in another thread? http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/loading-images-asynchronously-on-iphone-using-nsinvocationoperation

Answer (score 0):

You are making synchronous call to get image data. That means during this period your main thread (UI thread) will remain blocked (provided this is not called from a thread, which I am assuming not as you are updating UI here which should always be in main UI thread. It essentially means you cannot do anything until the call returns. You can use asynchronous (non blocking way to do this. One example using Grand Central Dispatch (GCD)

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0),  ^{        
// This runs in background               

NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:imgURL]];
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];               


      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{                        
             //This block runs on main thread, so update UI
            UIImageView *userImage =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,size,userImageSize,userImageSize)];
        userImage.image = image;
            });    
    });
```

Or check out API like sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler in NSURLConnection